# Azure API Management policy: validate request body against json schema

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to implement a content validation policy in Azure API management.
I created a schema named `event`.

The policy looks like this:

```
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="12000" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="validationErrors">
    <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" schema-id="event" schema-ref="#/components/schemas/event" />
</validate-content>
```

When I try to test it, I get an error message in trace saying that the schema reference is wrong:

```
"details": "Could not resolve schema reference '#/components/schemas/event'. Path '', line 1, position 1."
```

Documentation says:

```
<content type="content type string" validate-as="json|xml|soap" schema-id="schema id" schema-ref="#/local/reference/path" action="ignore|prevent|detect" />
```

But I didn't find any clue how to find the `schema-id` and the `schema-ref` attributes.

When I open the schema there's nothing like this on the screen neither in the "Overview" nor under "Properties". Please someone tell me how to fill these to make the policy working. Or, if it exists, point me to the documentation where I can read it :)

Answer (score 0):

`schema-id` and  `schema-ref` both are optional attributes for validating request body against json schema.

As per this [Azure API Management validation policies | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#attributes):

**schema-id:** Name of an existing schema that was [added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#schemas-for-content-validation) to the API Management instance for content validation. If not specified, the default schema from the API definition is used.
**schema-ref:** For a JSON schema specified in `schema-id`, optional reference to a valid local reference path in the JSON document. Example: `#/components/schemas/address`. The attribute should return a JSON object that API Management handles as a valid JSON schema.

Make sure to check [Azure API Management validation policies | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#schemas-for-content-validation) schemas for content validation, provide correct schema location whether you are importing from a file or URL.

Comment: I've read this. The question was, if I have a schema named "event" how do I know the schema-id and schema-ref to fill them in the policy as these are nowhere to be found on screen?

Comment: Even I am not sure about how to get that in portal. But you can give a try in Azure powershell to get the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementapischema?view=azps-7.3.0

Answer (score 0):

As @madhuraj has mentioned **schema-id** is the name of the schema which you have added in the 'Schemas' section of the Azure APIM.
The **schema-ref** is the path to the schema definition in your API specification(swagger/OpenAPI).
@vilmarci the **schema-ref** is optional, but you have given an incorrect path i.e. '#/components/schemas/event'.
Try without the **schema-ref** it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically under **API->Schemas** we can define JSON document with name (Id). For example, we can define schema **LoginAPI** with different definitions under it,

```
{
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "LoginModel": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "email",
                    "password"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "email": "definition",
                    "password": "definition"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in validate-content configuration you can use **schema-id="LoginAPI"** and **schema-ref="#/components/schemas/LoginModel"**.